# Допустимо ли сказать "медведик"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, словообразование

Допустимо ли сказать "медведик"?

Какие ещё уменьшительно-ласкательные формы есть у слова "медведь"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, конечно, так можно говорить.
В толковом словаре Ефремовой:
[медве́дик](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/184907/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BA), *м., разг.*
1) *уменьш. к сущ.* медведь;
2) *ласк. к сущ.* медведь.

Однокоренные слова:
медвежонок, медвежоночек, медве́душка (медве́дюшка, медведушко), медве́дко; медведище, медведица, медведиха, медвежатина, медвежатинка, медвежатник, медвежатница,  медвежий, медвежачий, медвежатничать, по-медвежьи.

Встречаются и "совсем разговорные" варианты: медвежулька, межвежулечка, [медведочка](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/7331626/).

Answer (score 1):

Да, такая форма вполне допустима. Суффикс -ик относится к уменьшительно-ласкательным и, следовательно, используется для создания образа предмета, характеризующегося, скажем, более мягким темпераментом, податливостью и добротой. Приведу примеры, раскрывающие в некоторой степени сферу использования (она, можно сказать, ничем не ограничивается, кроме родовой формы слова) данного суффикса и способ образования уменьшительно-ласкательных слов:

Ёжик — **м.р**, уменьшительно-ласкательная форма, образованная прибавлением суффикса -ик к основе слова — "ёж". Предмет **живой** природы;

Прутик — **м.р**, *разбор по аналогии*. Предмет **неживой** природы.

Как видите, суффикс достаточно широко распространён, однако, как Вы, скорее всего, заметили, может использоваться только со словами **мужского рода**.

Другие примеры слов с уменьшительно-ласкательным значением, являющихся производными от слова "медведь":

Медвежонок (суффикс -онок. Обратите внимание на чередование "д" с "ж"), медведушка (суффикс -ушк).

Comment: А разве "медвежонок" не является ли просто ребёнком медведя, а не является уменьшительно-ласкательным? Ну я так понимаю, что это разные вещи.

Comment: А это уже лексическое значение слова. Данным словом можно именовать и детёныша медведя, и взрослую особь, выражая ласку. Но в обоих случаях слово является производным от "медведь" и является уменьшительно-ласкательным.

Comment: В качестве уменьшительного для меня естественнее всего "**мишка**". "_Медведик_" же больше ассоциируется с украинизмом "**ведмедик**" в переводе названия конфеты "Мишка косолапый".

Comment: Саш, уточняю: "Ведмедик клишаногий", я ела! в детстве!

Comment: Да, я тоже помню - у меня бабушка в Киеве жила :)

Comment: Писал про медведя, а получился разговор про конфеты... Эх, аж есть захотелось :\